# React Lifecycle method when the browser back button is pushed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, back

Lets say I have two pages on my website, Home and Settings.

A user visits Home, then presses Settings. They decide to go back to Home via the back button, or pressing escape on the key board, or sliding two fingers from left to right, or some other way other than creating a new request.

Does react have a method that captures an event like this?

Comment: You want to handle history? (Not to let the browser handle it?)

Comment: No just want to trigger a function from componentDidMount that is no longer triggering.

Comment: [react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router) might be what you need...

Answer (score 0):

React itself doesn't contains any API's to work with history.

If you want to do this by hand, consult with window.history API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history

As mentioned in comments, [react-router](https://rackt.github.io/react-router/) can help you do this in react-way and also handles additional things, like remembering window position